# ¿Cuál es el tipo de dato para longitud y latitud Mysql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Visual Basic, con Visual Studio, utilizando una API para mapear (greatmaps.codeplex.com).
Cuando añado un marcador, lo que quiero es guardar la posición del mismo en una base de datos, para poder utilizarlo nuevamente cuando se cierra y abre el programa.
Esta es la base de datos, con una sola tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hago es que al momento de colocar el marcador en el mapa, guardo la longitud y latitud en dos variables de tipo double, por lo cual la sentencia insert que hago es esta:

```
insert into personas
values ('" & idpers & "','" & txtNombre.Text & "','" & txtApe.Text & "','" & txtTel.Text & "','" & txtDire.Text & "','" & cboxZona.SelectedItem & "','" & txtLatBD.Text & "','" & txtLngBD.Text & "')"
```

En "txtLatBD.Text" y "txtLngBD.Text" se encuentra esto, respectivamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al ingresarlo, me sale este error:

> Data truncated for column "latitud" at row 1

Desde la consola MySQL me ingresa perfectamente esos valores. También traté de cambiarle el tipo de dato a float, o decimal(9,6), pero me sale lo mismo.

Comment: Una opción sería usar spatial data types. Ver:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html y https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-data.html Esta sería la opción más **profesional** y más correcta además te permite guardar **posiciones** como una sola columna. Aunque quizá cueste un poco entender cómo funciona al principio. O bien usar `DECIMAL`
 dándole un tamaño adecuado para que los datos no queden truncados. Eso sí, hay que ser preciso sobre todo si necesitas hacer cálculos con los datos.

Comment: Para lo único que traería esos datos de la bd es para ubicarlos en el mapa en el evento Load, es decir, que quede "guardado" el marcador. Con decimal ya traté, y me sale "incorrect decimal value '-32,2943883126231' for column 'latitud' in row 1".                               Voy a mirar esa documentación, tal vez pueda de esa forma

Comment: Es mejor, y más exacto, empezar trabajando con los tipos de datos correspondientes a la información que queremos guardar. Ya MySQL posee un tipo de dato `POINT` entonces ¿por qué no usarlo?. Aunque ahora sólo tengas una necesidad mínima, tu aplicación puede evolucionar con el tiempo y si no has empezado usando el tipo de datos adecuado, actualizar la app sería más difícil cuando ya tengas datos en ella. [Mira esta parte donde explica como insertar ese tipo de datos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html).

Comment: La sentencia quedó así                                                                    `"insert into personas values ('" & idpers & "','" & txtNombre.Text & "','" & txtApe.Text & "','" & txtTel.Text & "','" & txtDire.Text & "','" & cboxZona.SelectedItem & "',ST_GeomFromText('POINT('" & a & "' '" & b & "')'))"`. Me da error de sintaxis con esta, pero desde la consola me funcionó perfecto, tengo que encontrar el error y listo. Y ya que guarda la longitud y latitud en una misma columna, se puede mostrar por separado esos datos?

Comment: Algún símbolo de más o de menos. Por otra parte usa sentencias preparadas para que el código sea más seguro. No uso vb.net pero seguro en la red encontrarás ejemplos de sentencias preparadas. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) seria la mejor opcion su precision.

A diferencia de varchar, puedes hacer operaciones matematicas como por ejemplo saber la distancia entre cada punto(por lo que tambien te ahorras un casting o conversion).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que la mayoría utiliza para este tipo de casos es VARCHAR, se envía como una String.

Comment: No es correcto. Se suele usar `DECIMAL` o `FLOAT`. ¿Qué tal si necesitas calcular los datos? En ese caso un VARCHAR no te serviría para nada.

Comment: En este caso en particular tal vez VARCHAR me serviría?, ya que las coordenadas son guardadas solamente para ubicar los marcadores "guardados" cuando se inicie el mapa en el evento Load.

Comment: Pues sí te serviría, en caso de que necesites calcular puedes parsear los datos para convertirlos en Float